# Problem when executing integration test and veryfing a list of beans with Mockito

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

Hello i'm facing a problem when verifying if an interface implementation was called on a integration test.

I have a service handler that injects a list of all interface implementations and executes the method.

I know that the service is called because I debugged it, but when verifying with mockito says that no interaction was found.

I don't know exactly why this is happening. My hypothesis is that when the integration test run and spring injects the list of beans is getting a different bean that I used "@SpyBean", so basically the bean that executes is different that i am spying.

When i run the test by itself it works, when i run all the tests with maven it fails saying that was encountered in this object.

The code is like this (is simplified of course)

```
@Component
class ServiceHandler {

    @Autowired
    private List<Interface> services;

    public void handler() {
        var integrationService =
                services.stream()
                        .filter(s -> s.integrationServiceType().equals(Enum.Service))
                        .findFirst().orElseThrow();
        integrationService.call();
    }
}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ServiceHandlerTest {
    @SpyBean
    private final InterfaceImpl serviceImpl;

    @Test
    void test() {
        // ...
        verify(serviceImpl, times(1)).call();
    }
}
```

I also tried to use BeanPostProcessor, i just expect to verify if the bean was called, i know its being called because i logged the execution when executing the tests

Comment: That should be `verify(serviceImpl, times(1)).call()`

Comment: Can you verify if the service is different in your test and your component? Write out its identity with `System.identityHashCode` in both the test and the component. If it is different, then you have different beans. My guess: `@SpyBean` is a wrapper bean and your `services` list actually has two elements (the real bean and the spy bean).

Comment: They are indeed different, any sugestion to get the same bean to spy on test and the service class?

Comment: How many elements are in your `services` list?

Comment: When i log with log.debug("List<Interface> {}", integrationServices); it prints a list of one element which its correct, now its have only concrete class

But the element inside the list have a different hashCode than the object with @SpyBean on test

Comment: I tried to come up with a [mre] myself with `interface Interface`, `@Component class InterfaceImpl`, `Enum.Service`, and an `@Autowired ServiceHandler handler` in the test. The spy bean is correctly wired and is the same instance as the one in the test class (Spring Boot 2.7.15). Please provide a _complete_ MRE that shows failure to execute. As it stands, this question is unanswerable; VTC for now until more details are provided